# IIS PHP 5.5 - HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length

Tags: php, curl, iis-7

I am using PHP in IIS 7.
Earlier I was having PHP 5.3 it was working fine.
Now I migrated to PHP 5.5 and I am getting "HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length." error on curl requests.

I was googling the solution but unable to get the any hint.

Below is the sample code which I am using:

```
    $request = "https://example.com?searchTxt=" . $keyword . "&count=" . $count;
    $data = "[1]";
    $data_encoded = utf8_encode($data);
    // Initialize the session
    $session = curl_init($request);
    // Set curl options
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_encoded)));
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_encoded);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, USERNAME . ':' . PASSWORD);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE); // Display communication with server
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM ) ; 
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_CAINFO, CERTIFICATE_PATH);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)');
    // Make the request
    $response = curl_exec($session);
```

Comment: Normally you don't need to set the content length in `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`,

Comment: But I have added that. Is there any issue with that?? It was working fine in PHP 5.3

Comment: @Raptor Hey Thank you, I have removed "'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_encoded)"  and its working fine. But I am unable to get. What was the issue with that line??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add explicitly the Content Length in request header. cURL will add (count) the length and add it if needed.

Since `strlen()` is not multi-byte friendly, `strlen(utf8_encode($data_encoded))` is not working as you expected. For UTF-8 characters, you should use `mb_strlen()` instead. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strlen.php)

Also, if your `$data_encoded` is not encoded in ISO-8859-1, the function is also not working as you expect; the function is literally a ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8 converter. See [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php)

Last, according to your code, `$data_encoded` comes from nowhere.